# JS code makes IE9 and Safari freezing and does not work in Opera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I don't know why, but this code makes IE9 and Safari crash, and does not work at all in Opera.

```
$('#contentPage').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    if($(".iframey[date-current]").length){
    $(".iframey:not(.hidden)").prevUntil("iframe").addClass('smaller');
}});
```

What should I do to make this code work in all browsers?

---edit---

The code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rzP5S/

Working grate in chrome and firefox

Comment: What does "crash" mean? The whole browser closes/hangs, or the code just doesn't do anything, or...?

Comment: Have you tried putting a semicolon `;` at the end of everything (so it finishes with `}});`? That's how it should technically be

Comment: So... it basically doesn't work in any browser? (-FF)

Comment: @nnnnnn the browser freezing and have to close it Through task manager

Comment: You'd better debug your code, like using firebug for FF or Chrome's inspector. They should tell you what the problems are in your js code.

Comment: Re Opera, it doesn't support `DOMSubtreeModified` and never has, so this can't possibly work on Opera.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code? Perhaps somebody can suggest a better way

Comment: Is the iframe that you're adding the class to inside `#contentPage`? Because if so wouldn't this cause an endless loop because when the DOM is modified you add a class, which is itself a modification, etc?

Comment: what's the version of jquery? you cannot pass "iframe" to `prevUntil()` in recent versions. it has to be dom node or jquery object

Comment: i'm trying to add Class .smaller to 3 article tags from any iframe not has class hidden. i'm using jq 1.8

Comment: in 1.8 you can't specify "iframe", check the manual though I don't know if that'd fix your issue.

Comment: This is the full code http://jsfiddle.net/rzP5S/ work only on chrome and firefox, I need it badly to work on all browsers

Comment: @veredesmarald so what should i do to make this code jsfiddle.net/rzP5S working in opera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Musa is saying is correct. There is an infinite loop. Is there any reason why you need to handle it in `DOMSubtreeModified`? Can't you just do the work within the click event instead? This seems to behave the same:

```
$(".onePost").live("click", function() {

    $(".onePost").removeClass('smaller');

    $("iframe")
        .addClass('hidden')
        .removeAttr('src')
        .removeAttr('date-current');

    $(this).nextAll("iframe:eq(0)")
        .removeClass('hidden')
        .removeAttr('style')
        .attr({src: $(this).data('href')})
        .attr('date-current', 'here');

    if($(".iframey[date-current]").length){
        $(".iframey:not(.hidden)").prevUntil(".iframey").addClass('smaller');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rPPSj/

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the dom in a dom modified event handler, you should check if the modification was due to your code in the handler to prevent an endless loop.

Also

> Warning! the DOMSubtreeModified event type is defined in this specification for reference and completeness, but this specification deprecates the use of this event type.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified